# Asp.net Repeater row count

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

Can anyone tell me how to do a running count in a repeater? I've made this code that works but the variable (RC) doesn't seem to be counting up. Here's the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="FPRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="FPDataSource">

           <ItemTemplate>
               <%Dim RC As Int32
                   Dim divc As String%>
                   <%If (RC + 1 Mod 1 = 0) Then
                           divc = "one-third mobile-collapse"
                       ElseIf (RC + 1 Mod 2 = 0) Then
                           divc = "one-third one-third-second mobile-collapse"
                       ElseIf (RC + 1 Mod 3 = 0) Then
                           divc = "one-third one-third-last mobile-collapse"
                       End If%>

                    <div class="<%=divc %>">
        <img src="/images/<%# Eval("ImName")%>" alt="<%# Eval("Heading")%>" />      
                            <h2><%# Eval("Heading")%></h2>                   
                           <p><%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("ContText"))%></p>                   
                        </div>
               <%RC = (RC + 1)%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater><!--/info-box-->

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FPDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblContent] WHERE (Location = 'Home') AND (Deleted = 'False') Order By OrderBy ASC">
```

What i'd thought would happen is that <%RC = (RC + 1)%> would automatically add 1 to RC every time the row repeated.

All it currently does is pull back 1, 1, 1 instead of 1, 2, 3. Where am i going wrong? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you handle the [OnItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event and do any changes from there. This event is called on each row and you can get the row number by looking at the [RepeaterItemEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritemeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, you could try declaring RC outside the row, the way you do it assure it'll always be 0

Comment: Thanks... I've tried to declaring RC outside the row but it fails every time. Do you have an example i could look at?  I've taken a look at  OnItemDataBound but the example is a bit confusing. I'll need to do some more googling i think.

Comment: have you tried using Container.DataItemIndex instead of RC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put down below lines above your repeater control

```
<script runat="server">
        Dim RC As Int32 = 1
</script>
```

As well as remove `Dim RC As Int32` from ItemTemplate

Comment: Brilliant - your changes work as i was hoping. My Mod part doesn't so i'll now try fix that. Thanks for your time!